# How to find the execution time of query in Impala using Hue UI.

Tags: hive, impala, hue, bigdata

Although this question has already been asked, there is no concrete solution. I will highly appreciate your answers. In log I cannot see any execution time that we can see on Hive.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing the version of Hue you are running, I will assume it is the latest version.

Hue 3.11 shows the execution time in the top-right corner:

[Location of execution time for Impala query in Hue 3.11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XWbt.png)